# Spring Cloud Version compatible for Spring Boot 2.5.5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

I'm trying to build a microservice application which will be using Hystrix and some distributed tracing from Spring Cloud. When i tried using Spring Cloud version '2021.0.0-M3' for the Spring boot version '2.5.5' I get below error while startup:

***Your project setup is incompatible with our requirements due to following reasons:

- Spring Boot [2.5.5] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train***

Is there a compatibility matrix between spring boot and Spring Cloud.

Comment: Please add your pom.xml file

Comment: Have you try `2020.0.4` or `2020.0.5-SNAPSHOT`, I remember that `2021.0.0-M3` is compatible with spring boot `2.6.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Spring Cloud Release** mapping with **Spring Boot compatibility**:

1. 2020.0.x aka Ilford  ----> Spring Boot 2.4.x, 2.5.x (Starting with 2020.0.3)
2. Hoxton               ----> Spring Boot 2.2.x, 2.3.x (Starting with SR5)
3. Greenwich            ----> Spring Boot 2.1.x
4. Finchley             ----> Spring Boot 2.0.x
5. Edgware              ----> Spring Boot 1.5.x
6. Dalston              ----> Spring Boot 1.5.x

Source: [documentation link](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud)

Comment: 1. Please reproduce the text of your screenshot into your answer. Pictures of text aren't parseable by screenreaders, search engines, or those of us whose corporate networks block imgur. 2. Please state your source -- where did you get this info, how do we know it's legit, and where can we go in the future to see new releases' compatibility.

Comment: Agreed, will post the text data